# Not updating list in the panel at the run time in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

i have two panel. when i'm click on the left panel items its calling web service and populating the right panel and same time its updating the number of items in the right panel to the left panel item which is clicked.
for first time its updating the left panel items but when i click on the other left panel item its not updating left panel items again.
its updating only first time.

my code is:

```
   onInboxListTap:function (dataview, index, item, record) {
    console.log('Inside onInboxListTap function');
    var queuestore = dataview.getStore();
    var rec = queuestore.getAt(index);
    console.log(rec.data.workSetName);
    var store = Ext.getStore('InboxWorkitemStore');
    store.clearData();                        //Function  To clear WorkitemStore
    //creating object of InboxQueueServices class
    var inboxQueueServiceObject =
    Ext.create('InfoImage.common.services.InboxQueueServices', {   
        config:{
            scope:this

        }
    }, this.onQueueContentRetrievalSuccess, this.onQueueContentRetrievalFailure());
    // calling loadQueueContent function to load queue contents
    inboxQueueServiceObject.loadQueueContent(rec.data.workSetName);


  },
 //To call Function onQueueContentRetrievalSuccess after loadQueueContent successful
  onQueueContentRetrievalSuccess:function () {

    console.log('Inside onQueueContent Retrieval Success function');

    var store = Ext.getStore('InboxWorkitemStore');               
    //Getting componenet queueDetails list
    var inboxWorkitemList = Ext.getCmp('inboxWorkitemList'); 
    var queueDetails = Ext.getCmp('queueDetails');
    var queueList = Ext.getCmp('queuelist');                  //Getting component list
    var queueViewPanel = Ext.getCmp('queueViewPanel');        //Getting queueViewPanel
    queueDetails.setStore(store);
      store.sync();
    var queueCount = store.getCount();                        
    if (queueCount > 0) {
        var queueItem = store.getAt(0);
        var queueStore = queueList.getStore();
              queueStore.each(function (record) {
               if (record.get('workSetName') == queueItem.get('sourceWorkstep')) {
                record.data.queueName = queueItem.get('sourceWorkstep') + '(' +   
                queueCount + ')';

            }
        });

         queueList.setStore(queueStore);
        queueStore.sync();
        queueList.getStore().each(function (record) {
            console.log('queueList:' + record.data.queueName);
        });
      console.log('store UPDATED');
    }
    queueList.refresh();
    console.log('store count: ' + store.getCount());
    console.log(queueDetails);
    // navigates the panel
    queueViewPanel.animateActiveItem(
        inboxWorkitemList, {
            type:'slide',
            direction:'up',
            duration:250
        });

},
```

Please help me on this isssue.

Comment: Please someone help me.its very important for me.

Comment: 12 questions, 7 answered and NONE accepted. Please read this : http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have to set record for that i resolve it.

```
  queueStore.each(function (record) {
               if (record.get('workSetName') == workitem.get('sourceWorkset')) {
                record.data.queueName = workitem.get('sourceWorkset')
                    + '(' + queueCount + ')';
                // queueStore.updateRecord(record.data.queueName);
                record.set(record.data.queueName);
            }
        });
```